# ArduinoBLE.h - multiple values in one characteristic

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I recently read the documentation of the [ArduinoBLE.h](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLE) library. Under "Service design patterns" it is noted that it is possible to write multiple values to one characteristic:

[image: ArduinoBLE documentation - service design patterns]

How can I achieve that? Unfortunately I cannot find any information about this in the documentation.

I want to send all accelerometer data in one characteristic and all gyroscope data respectively along with a time stamp. This results in two characteristics

1. accChara: [time stamp, xAcc, yAcc, zAcc] and
2. gyroChara: [time stamp, xGyro, yGyro, zGyro],

where time stamp is an unsigned long (via millis()) and the values read are floats (note: I am using the [Arduino_LSM9DS1.h](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoLSM9DS1) library for the IMU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states (as posted in your image):

> The accelerometer characteristic above, for example, takes 11 bytes as a **ASCII-encoded string**.

They just created a comma separated string containing all their data ("200,133,150") and transmitted it using [writeValue](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLEBLECharacteristicwriteValue). You could do the same for your values and convert them back to numbers on your receiving end. Another way would be to use a [struct](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Struct/) to hold and send your data.